# how do I create validation rules from a GraphQL schema

Tags: validation, graphql

How can I transform a simple GraphQL schema, which I can access server-side by importing and client-side by querying, into validation rules?

I can kind of see how I could do this for enums, lets say I have a title:

```
  enum Title {
    Mr, Ms, Mrs, Dr
  }
```

I could access the possible values by querying

```
  __type (name: "Title") {
    name
    enumValues {
      name
    }
  }
```

And now I can create a drop-down on the client or a validation on the server, but how do I encode and access for example the min/max length of a string field? Or min/max value for a number?

Do I need to add a custom type for each field? Or is, there a better way?

---

[edit] in response to Daniel's answer:

I'm using yup for validation, which is a great library, but for example if a certain field was *required* on a gql InputType, how do I get that into the yup schema?

And how do I use that yup schema on the front-end? Ideally I would like to serialise it, send it to the client, and reconstruct the validation there.

The only other way I can think of is to share the code, but then I need to re-build and re-deploy the client each time the schema changes, which is of course out of the question :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of kinds of data validation, for example:

- Data type (is this value a string or number?)
- Range (is this value within this range of values?)
- Constraint (does this value satisfy this regex expression?)
- Consistency (is the end date after the start date?)
- Referential (does the provided identifier reference an entity that actually exists?)

Strongly typed languages like GraphQL can only really provide data type validation. Your GraphQL service may perform other kinds of validation (through your data source, your data models, custom GraphQL scalars, etc.) -- however, only *type* information can be introspected from the service. Introspection is not the appropriate tool for communicating other validation logic to your client.

If you're using Node.js on the backend and your intent is to share validation logic between your backend and your frontend, then the best approach would be to utilize a library like [yup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup) or [joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hapi/joi).

Comment: Thank you! I actually *am* using yup for validation, but I don't see how that prevents me from having to duplicate information. I've made an edit to the question to explain what I mean.

Comment: You won't avoid duplication between your yup schema and your GraphQL schema -- in the same way there would be duplication between the types in your database and the types in your data model or GraphQL type. You'd need to utilize something like [this library](https://github.com/WASD-Team/yup-ast) to serialize the yup schema. Whether you use GraphQL or another endpoint to make this available to your client is up to you.

Comment: There may be more appropriate libraries for serializing the schema. That's just the first one I stumbled upon. I've used yup before, but only ever used a common module to share the schema between my applications, so YMMV.

Comment: ok, I guess that'll have to do then. Thanks for the link, being able to serialise a yup schema will go a long way!